# Railo instanceof not working with Jsoup

Tags: jsoup, railo, cfml

I'm running a linux server with tomcat and Railo. If I try this simple code:

```
check = "";
jSoupClass = createObject( "java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup" );

if(IsInstanceOf(jSoupClass,"org.jsoup.Jsoup")){
 check = "ok";      
}

writeDump(check );
```

If I run this simple code the var `check` is always empty. I run this simple test with many java class and all working perfectly.

In my app I use jsoup with no problem, but cannot seem to run this simple check. I use this for check the doctype of a document:

```
jSoupClass = createObject( "java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup" );
dom = jSoupClass.connect( "http://www.mutuiinpdap.net" ).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6").timeout(10000).execute();

doc = dom.parse();
nods = doc.childNodes();
doctype = {};
for (key in nods) {
  if(IsInstanceOf(key,"org.jsoup.nodes.DocumentType")){
doctype.string = key.toString();
switch(key) {
 case "<!DOCTYPE html>":
      doctype.declarations = "Html 5";
  break;
     case '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">':
  doctype.declarations = "XHTML transitional";
  break;
    }
   }
  }

writeDump(doctype);
```

Is there a way to solve this? can I use a different code to check which doctype is a document?

This code run perfectly on my local Windows machine. But on my production server with Ubuntu installed on it breaks...

[Edit]

I have tested also with this code:

```
public function getDoctype(){



 myClass = {};


jSoupClass = createObject( "java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup" );
whois = createObject("java", "org.apache.commons.net.whois.WhoisClient");



myClass.jj = "ko";
myClass.ww = "ko";



writeDump(jSoupClass);  
writeDump(whois);   

if(IsInstanceOf(jSoupClass,"org.jsoup.Jsoup")){
    myClass.jj = "ok";      
}


if(IsInstanceOf(whois,"org.apache.commons.net.whois.WhoisClient")){
    myClass.ww = "ok";      
}


return myClass;
```

}

I will get a myClass.jj = "ko";  and myClass.ww = "ok";

Comment: I can't see why isInstanceOf isn't working - especially if it works on one install but not another - can you [raise a bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO) with relevant details.

Comment: I would like to raise a bug with relevan details, but there is not much more to add. I have add a try/catch to my code to see what's wrong, but get no errors. I have update my question with further example...I cannot be sure this is a railo bug or Jsoup bug. I've fired some question on both groups but no one seems to be interested...

Comment: For reference, links to: [Railo Discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/railo/NvylfseXN6Y) and [Jsoup Discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jsoup/edTpR8XtSFk).

Comment: The relevant details are (1) a clear description of what's misbehaving (i.e. isInstanceOf returning false when it possibly shouldn't) 
(2) the versions of Railo, Jsoup, and your JVM, and (3) a reproducable test-case - i.e. the code snippets in your question and the jsoup jar. If you [raise it on Jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO) Micha/Igal will see and investigate further - it might be closed as not a Railo issue, but that's probably a question for Micha as to whether isInstanceOf should work for static/non-inited objects.

Comment: *whether isInstanceOf should work for static/non-inited objects.* IMO it should. This might not be the issue, but I had a similar problem with ACF8/9 when using the javaLoader. `isInstanceOf` returned false because my object was created by a different class loader ie javaLoader than the main one used by CF. As Railo supports dynamic class loading it might be related(?).

Answer (score 1):

For a DOCTYPE to be valid it must be the first thing in a document, so there's no need to loop through nodes checking instances.

All you have to do is examine the first tag - that is, the contents of the HTML string before the first `>` character (or, for some XHTML, between the first and second `>`s)

You also don't need (or want) a long list of full doctype declarations. Aside from HTML 5, they all follow the same pattern (i.e. have a DTD), so you can simply extract the name from the doctype.

I've wrapped that logic up into the function posted below - may need some tweaking or extra work to perform how you need, but it's been tested briefly and works. Hopefully it is all self-explanatory, but let me know if any parts are not.

```
jSoupClass = createObject( "java" , "org.jsoup.Jsoup" , "./jsoup-1.7.1.jar" );

doc = jSoupClass
    .connect( "http://www.mutuiinpdap.net" )
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
    .timeout(10000)
    .execute()
    ;

doctype = determineDoctype( doc.body() );

writeDump(doctype);



function determineDoctype( Html )
{

    var FirstTag = trim(ListFirst(Arguments.Html,'>'));

    if ( LCase(trim(FirstTag)) EQ '<!doctype html' )
        return 'Html 5';

    if ( Left(FirstTag,5) EQ '<?xml' )
        FirstTag = trim(ListGetAt(Arguments.Html,2,'>'));

    if ( Left(LCase(FirstTag),14) NEQ '<!doctype html' )
        return 'Non-HTML doctype [#FirstTag#]' ;

    var dtd = rematch('-//W3C//DTD [^/]+',FirstTag);

    if ( ArrayLen(dtd) )
        return ListRest(dtd[1],' ');

    return 'Unknown Doctype [#FirstTag#]';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test `object.getClass().getName() EQ 'org.jsoup.Jsoup'` to see if the class is what you expect.

Even though this would solve the issue with your code, I'd still recommend the other answer I posted for determining doctype.